# Regular Expression for first address line with special requirements

Tags: java, regex, validation

I am very new to regular expressions and I am attempting to write one that allows me to validate addresses (specifically, a line 1 of an address. not full) with the following special requirements:

**Allowed values: alphanumeric, -, ', ., #, /, (comma), [space]**

I've created the following, but it doesn't work for something simple as "110 W Cityline Dr"

Regular Expression: **^[a-zA-Z 0-9.\,#-\'/]*$**

EDIT: Per Suggestion, I am using the following: ^[a-zA-Z 0-9-.\,#\'/]*$. This seems to be working.

Comment: [`^[a-zA-Z 0-9.\,#-\'/]*$` matches `110 W Cityline Dr`](https://regex101.com/r/xAi1RD/1) though you should know that `-` here creates a range between `#` (index 35) and `'` (index 39).

Comment: Apologies, my JUNIT's were incorrectly organized! -- so what would be the proper regular expression to remove the range?

Comment: Move the `-` to the end or start of the character class, or escape it.